# Assigning unique references to input fields within an iteration

Tags: reactjs

I have a table that gets generated by a fetched map and builds a row for each `payer` within this map.

Each row contains `payer name`, two input fields, and a button with an `onClick` event handler.

On submit, the system shall take

- `payer id`,
- `transaction id` (gathered from `props`),
- `payer value` (a custom field not related to payer object)
- `payer notes` (again, a custom field not related to payer object)

and `POST` this to an endpoint.

**I am looking for a way to pass the correct parameters to the `onClick` handler - when there are an indefinite amount of inputs generated - as my current solution only registers the last field in the map.**

*You will see that I use some references within the input elements* - *I was experimenting with them to see if I can achieve some sort of result, however, I had no luck* - *and, yes, they were declared in the constructor*.

> constructor

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        payers: []
    }

    this.closeModal = this.closeModal.bind(this);
    this.confirmTransaction = this.confirmTransaction.bind(this);
}
```

> Relevant `render()`

```
render() {

    const tableHeader = (
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td>Value</td>
                <td>Notes</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    )

    const payersList = this.state.payers.map(payer => {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <tr>
                    <td className="font-italic" key={payer.id}>{payer.name}</td>
                    <td>
                        <input className="form-control form-control-sm" type="text" placeholder={this.props.transaction.debit} ref={value => this.payerValue = value} />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input className="form-control form-control-sm" type="text" ref={notes => this.payerNotes = notes} />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <button onClick={() => this.confirmTransaction(this.props.transaction.id, payer.name, this.payerValue.value, this.payerNotes.value)}>OK</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </React.Fragment>
        )
    });
```

> Confirm transaction handler

```
confirmTransaction(id, name, value, notes) {
    alert(`This will set ${name} as a payer for transaction ${id} for the value of ${value} with the notes ${notes}`)
}
```

> Example output (missing ${value} and ${notes})

[image: Output]

Comment: question is very poorly written, please explain what you want clearly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well i would split this into 2 components and 1 container.

1. ListContainer : will hold you logic and render list
2. `<ListComponent payers={[..payers]} onClick={this.setPayer}/>` : this will render rowComponent
3. `<RowComponent payer={{id:1}} onClick={props.onClick} />` : this will render a row.

now props.onClick is a function on `ListContainer` and inside RowComponent you should call this function with the object you have.

example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-northcutt-jn769?fontsize=14

good luck :)

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

function Row({ payer, onClick }) {
  const [value, onChange] = useState(payer.value);

  // dont forget to update value if parent changed for somereason
  useEffect(() => {
    if (payer.value !== value) {
      onChange(payer.value);
    }
  }, [payer]);

  return (
    <li>
      <label>{payer.name}</label>
      <input value={value} onChange={e => onChange(e.target.value)} />
      <button onClick={e => onClick({ ...payer, value })}>save</button>
    </li>
  );
}

function ListComponent({ payers, onClick }) {
  return (
    <ul>
      {payers.map(payer => (
        <Row key={payer.id} payer={payer} onClick={onClick} />
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
}

function ListContainer() {
  const [payers, addPayer] = useState([
    { id: 1, name: "a", value: 1 },
    { id: 2, name: "b", value: 2 }
  ]);
  function setPayer(payer) {
    alert("payer is " + JSON.stringify(payer));
    addPayer(payers.filter(i => i.id !== payer.id).concat(payer));
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ListComponent onClick={setPayer} payers={payers} />
      <pre>{JSON.stringify(payers, null, 2)}</pre>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<ListContainer />, rootElement);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: @Kyan you welcome, i added condesnadbox to answer :).. check it out and if that resolve your question please check accept. ty and goodluck +1